# How to sum values from the same column, separated by a '|'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have a table that in one column it have values separated by |, I need to sum those values to know the total value. example 5|4|3   = 12. I thinked that if I replace the | for a + symbol, that should work. But it doenst work.

Here is my code to create the table and what I am using to sum the values.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_table](
    [totals] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
--*******************
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test_table]
           ([totals])
  --   VALUES
           (
select ('1|5|13')
union
select ('1|5|13')
union
select ('0|0|2')
union
select ('1|1|7')
union
select ('1|1|13')
union
select ('1|1|13')
union
select ('0|0|3')
union
select ('0|0|1')
union
select ('0|0|4')
union
select ('1|1|9'))
GO

select 
tot
--sum(tot) as total
--CONVERT(numeric, tot)
from 
(
select totals,
replace(totals,'|','+') as tot
from test_table
) qry
```

Comment: version of SQL Server?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656117/how-to-sum-numbers-in-a-delimited-string-using-sql-server

Comment: Ideally, you should be fixing your design here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum numbers in a delimited string using SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656117/how-to-sum-numbers-in-a-delimited-string-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server does not support macro substitution nor does if have an `EVAL()`.   If you don't want to go with Dynamic SQL and your requirement is a simple aggregation, consider a `CROSS APPLY` in concert with a `string_split()`

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  [test_table] A
 Cross Apply (
                Select SumTotal = sum(try_convert(int,value))
                 from string_split(Totals,'|') B1
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
totals  SumTotal
0|0|1   1
0|0|2   2
0|0|3   3
0|0|4   4
1|1|13  15
1|1|7   9
1|1|9   11
1|5|13  19
```

Comment: @ipeoples Always happy to help.